# C# with XDocument and xsi:schemaLocation

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, linq-to-xsd, xnamespace

I want to create the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyNode xsi:schemaLocation="https://MyScheme.com/v1-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://MyScheme.com/v1-0 Sscheme.xsd">
  <MyInfo>
    <MyNumber>string1</MyNumber>
    <MyName>string2</MyName>
    <MyAddress>string3</MyAddress>
  </MyInfo>
  <MyInfo2>
    <FirstName>string4</FirstName>
  </MyInfo2>
</MyNode>
```

I'm using this code.

```
    XNamespace xmlns = "https://MyScheme.com/v1-0 Sscheme.xsd";
    XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("https://MyScheme.com/v1-0");

    XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
         new XElement(xmlns + "MyNode",
             new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation),
             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
             new XElement("MyInfo",
                 new XElement("MyNumber", "string1"),
                 new XElement("MyName", "string2"),
                 new XElement("MyAddress", "string3")
                 ),
                 new XElement("MyInfo2",
                     new XElement("FirstName", "string4")
                     )
         )
     );
    xmlDocument.Save("C:\\MyXml.xml");
```

However, I'm getting xmlns="" inside tags MyInfo and MyInfo2.

Can somebody help me to create the correct XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `xmlns` `XNamespace` for all elements, because that is default namespace and it is declared at root level element. Note that descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace implicitly, unless otherwise specified :

```
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
         new XElement(xmlns + "MyNode",
             new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation),
             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
             new XElement(xmlns+"MyInfo",
                 new XElement(xmlns+"MyNumber", "string1"),
                 new XElement(xmlns+"MyName", "string2"),
                 new XElement(xmlns+"MyAddress", "string3")
                 ),
                 new XElement(xmlns+"MyInfo2",
                     new XElement(xmlns+"FirstName", "string4")
                     )
         )
     );
```

**<kbd>[Dotnetfiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1NBxXg)</kbd>**